# Why aren't these modules being resolved?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Here is the error output I get. I've tried creating a jsconfig.json to do what the errors describe as a solution but I'm just too inexperienced to understand what's going on...

All of these modules are installed in my node-modules folder.

I'm trying to build a Dapp using react truffle and web3js

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
> 'C:\Users\gavin\WebstormProjects\untitled\blockchain\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false } assets by status 6.88 KiB [cached] 1 asset assets by chunk 4.86 MiB (name: main)

The error I'm getting is much larger than this but stackoverflow won't allow me to post the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't following instructions properly. Made the correct changes to webpack.config.js and everything is working good.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).